# Visual Studio 2010 express compiler

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I would like to know if I can somehow compile c++ code in visual studio express 2010 with a 2019/2022 compiler. I only want to use express 2010 as an editor. I get no results on google regarding this topic.

Edit: I can change from platform toolset V100 to V90 but I'd like V143 like VS 2022. Is it possible though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but why on earth would you want to continue using Visual Studio Express 2010 as your IDE? VS2022 is so full of goodies and the community edition is free to use.

That being said: The VS2019/VS2022 compilers are just cl.exe, link.exe etc... You can use these compilers instead of the VS2010 cl.exe, link.exe etc... The VS2010 integrated build system will not automatically find them, so you'll either have to fiddle around with paths, get in to trouble with compiler switches etc...

You could switch to makefiles (or CMake) to use the compilers and keep the IDE. VS2010 is then no more than a fancy editor.

Tip: Try compiling your code from the command line (cmd.exe) to get started. Or download VS2022 community edition.

Comment: VS2022 takes 2 gigs of ram for features that I don't use, I've been compiling from the command line for quite some time now, and I thought there was some kind of option to switch the compiler. Thank you for responding!